# HTML5 Video Play Button Overlay Issue

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am creating a video player and cannot figure out how to get my video to play by clicking my playButton overlay. Ultimate goal is to get it to play by clicking the button and the button disappearing, when you want to pause you click the video and the play button reappears, but where I stand, I can't even get the video to play when I click the overlay play button.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<video class="video" id="video" loop controls onclick="playPause()">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<div class="playButton" onclick="playPause()"></div>
</div>
```

Script

```
var bunnyVideo = document.getElementById("video");
function playPause() { 
if (bunnyVideo.paused)
{           
        bunnyVideo.play();
}
  else 
  {
       bunnyVideo.pause();
  }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sbtL5bag/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your JavaScript *load type* `No wrap - in <body>` then it works.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbtL5bag/1/)

Comment: awesome thanks, any idea how to toggle that play button?

Comment: also is that No wrap - in <body> tag, a jsfiddle thing only? or do i specifically have to do something to it on my website?

Comment: @GiBiT09 The option specifies where your JavaScript is inputted into the page. The onLoad option loads after the page has loaded which is *after* the `playPause` function has been referenced in the elements `onclick` and in another scope. You could also warp the code in head but then you would also need to put the `bunnyVideo` initialization inside the function as the element `video` isn't available at the time head loads.

Comment: @GiBiT09 *ping*. Was the answer sufficient?

Comment: that portion of it was yes, I was trying to get it to work in my wordpress, but cannot get it to work.

Comment: @GiBiT09 Open the [Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and check the console for errors. Do you see any while trying to play the video?